# Category & Function

Tags: syntax, english, grammatical-category

I have the next two sentences, and I'm asked  to state the function and category of the parts in bold. I am introduced to the concepts of function and category, but I was applying what I learned about them on oversimple structures, but now I find these two sentences confusing, so I couldn't determine their category and function or to be more precise, I have an answer in my mind, but I'm not sure if it is acceptable.
The sentences are:

> 1. They are fond of bull-fighting, **which I find quite repulsive**.

I know that the part in bold has the category of non-restrictive relative clause, but I'm not sure about the function.

> 2. My wife hated the fact **that the children left their clothes strewn across the floor**.

In this example, I guess the category is an appositive clause, but I'm not settled about the function, so please could you tell me the category and function of each part?

Comment: (1) has a non-restrictive relative clause if the antecedent of _which_ is _bull-fighting_: “I find bull-fighting quite repulsive”. But can _which_ in (1) have the whole main clause as its antecedent? “I find their interest in bull-fighting quite repulsive”. This kind of clauses is called a _non-restrictive **continuative** relative clause_, if your classification allows this option. Sentences with continuative clauses can be considered a borderline case between subordination and coordination.

Comment: And _the fact the the children did this and that_ is what's known as a "factive noun phrase complement". The _factive_ part is because _fact_ presupposes its complement clause, and the _NP complement_ part is because they have a special grammar, behaving like verbal complements but modifying nouns, like _the story that Trump won the election_ (which is not factive).

Comment: 1. Yes, a non-restrictive relative clause. Its function is that of **supplementary adjunct**. 2.  A clause but not an appositive. It's a declarative content clause functioning as **complement** of "fact".

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *They are fond of bull-fighting,* [*which I find quite repulsive*].
>
> [2] *My wife hated the fact* [*that the children left their clothes strewn*
> *across the floor*].

You are right: the bracketed element in [1] is a supplementary (non-restrictive) relative clause. Its function is that of supplementary adjunct, a loosely attached expression set off by punctuation and intonation presenting supplementary non-integrated content.

In [2] the bracketed element is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of (thus licensed by) the head noun "fact". Some people would call it an appositive, but if a key feature of an appositive is its ability to stand alone in place of the whole NP, then [2] fails the test: **My wife hated that the children left their clothes strewn across the floor*.

In modern grammar, the perceived wisdom is that it is not a systematic feature of the noun + content clause structure that the latter can function as an appositive.

Note also that it cannot be promoted to subject: **That the children left* *their clothes strewn across the floor my wife hated*.

Comment: “My wife hated that ... is perfectly grammatical for me! I don’t quite get your last example. Isn’t it an example of proposing?

Comment: I don't think "hate" licenses a declarative content clause on its own. "It" is required, as in the object extraposition construction "My wife hated it that the children left their clothes strewn across the floor".

Comment: Just checked on COCA and BNC. Seems to be a marked UK/US split. *Hate* seems to take content clauses for many US speakers, but not UK ones.